# Trouble with writing a very basic SPARC Assembly routine that returns whether a number is odd

Tags: assembly, sparc

I'm writing a small assembly routine called isOdd, which, as the name implies, returns if the passed integer is odd, by returning 1 from a % operation.

This is my code so far:

```
Function prototype: int isOdd( long num )

isOdd:
    save     %sp, -96, %sp  ! Save caller's window

    mov      %i0, %o0       ! Parameter num goes to %o0
    mov      2, %l0         ! 2 goes to local register
    call     .rem           ! Call modulus subroutine
    nop

    mov      %o0, %l0       ! moves the result of the subroutine 
                            ! to output register o0
    ret
    restore
```

However, I don't get good output; in fact, it seems like it is just returning whatever value I pass to num, instead of actually doing the modulus operation.

Google hasn't proved helpful for such a basic question. This is my first assembly code, so I'm pretty unfamiliar with the concept of "registers," and I think mixing them up  is where my error may lie.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Are you sure you've got the "source" and "destination" of the `mov` instruction operands the right way around in all instances? Your code appears inconsistent with your comments.

Comment: It's `mov src, dst`, right? (check your last `mov`) Also, it's enough just to `and` it with 1 instead of modulo operation. Also, '2', parameter for modulo, should also go to an output register.

Comment: Hmm okay, I tried that, and now it just gives me a 0 answer for every value. Perhaps it has something to do with the registers I'm choosing? I wasn't sure which registers to use to save 2 and the result of the % call.

Comment: Why don't you just bitwise-and the input with 1? SPARC uses 2's complement like any sane architecture, so that produces the correct result.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a whole bunch of registers, which you can think of as being in blocks
of 8.  At any one time, three consecutive blocks of 8 registers are visible as
the current register window, and are labelled as `%o0`-`%o7`, `%l0`-`%l7`, and
`%i0`-`%i7`.  (There is a fourth block of 8 registers, `%g0`-`%g7`, which are
global rather than being a part of the windowing arrangement.)

When you `save` or `restore`, the window moves by *two* blocks of 8.  The
overlapping block allows for parameter and result passing.  The registers
which are named `%o0`-`%o7` in the caller are the same ones that are named
`%i0`-`%i7` in the callee.  (The two new blocks in the callee are `%l0`-`%l7`,
which are private for local use within that window, and `%o0`-`%o7` which the
callee can use when it in turn wants to call another function.)

It's clearer with a picture:

```
:                      :
+----------------------+
| Block of 8 registers |      caller's window
+----------------------+  +----------------------+
| Block of 8 registers |  |      %i0 - %i7       |    ---------.
+----------------------+  +----------------------+             | save
| Block of 8 registers |  |      %l0 - %l7       |             v
+----------------------+  +----------------------+  +----------------------+
| Block of 8 registers |  |      %o0 - %o7       |  |      %i0 - %i7       |
+----------------------+  +----------------------+  +----------------------+
| Block of 8 registers |              ^             |      %l0 - %l7       |
+----------------------+      restore |             +----------------------+
| Block of 8 registers |              `---------    |      %o0 - %o7       |
+----------------------+                            +----------------------+
| Block of 8 registers |                                callee's window
+----------------------+
:                      :
```

Your caller places the `num` argument into `%o0` (in its window), then calls
you.  You `save` to set up a new window, and so you see it in `%i0` in your
window.

`.rem` takes two parameters.  You place these in your `%o0` and `%o1` (in your
window), then call it.  It will see them in its `%i0` and `%i1` (assuming it does
a `save` to set up a new window).  It puts the answer in its `%i0`, which is
your `%o0`.

Similarly, you should put your result in your `%i0`; whoever called you will see it
in their `%o0`.

Answer (score 0):

```
! modified based on comments 

isOdd:
  save     %sp, -96, %sp  ! Save caller's window
  mov      %i0, %o0       ! Parameter num goes to %o0
  mov      2, %o1         ! 2 goes to %o1
  call     .rem           ! Call modulus subroutine
  nop

  mov      %o0, %i0       ! moves the result of the subroutine 
                          ! to input register i0
  ret
  restore
```